# Find row where values change from positive to negative and insert blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below which takes a table of data, removes most of the columns and any rows where the value in column C is zero, and finally sorts by column C.

What I need to be able to do next is find the row where the values in column C change from positive to negative and insert 5 blank rows.

I can find other code examples which loop through the values to perform a number of tasks but I just need insert rows where the values change from positive to negative.

```
Sub FormatData()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer

Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")

FirstRow = wsData.Range("C2").Row
LastRow = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Columns("C:Y").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("D:F").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

wsData.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Select

For lrow = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 3)
If workrange.Value = "0" _
    Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete

Next lrow

LastRow2 = wsData.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:C" & LastRow2).Sort Key1:=Range("C2:C" & LastRow2), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like the following loop to the end of your sub after your sorting code:

```
FirstRow = wsData.Range("C2").Row
LastRow = wsData.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = FirstRow To LastRow
    If wsData.Cells(lrow, 3).Value >= 0 And wsData.Cells(lrow + 1, 3).Value <= 0 Then
        For x = 1 To 5
        wsData.Rows(lrow + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        Next x
    Exit For
    End If
Next lrow
```

Comment: I was just starting to type an answer and saw another answer pop-up.  Looks about the same as where I was going, except I had added a filters to the spreadsheet, sorted by column(3), then found the first instance of a value >=0 and inserted 5 rows above it.  Similar outcome.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Comment: I suggest you change `LastRow` to be based on the last non-empty cell in column `C` rather than column `A`.